# Applying Work energy Theorem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, work, velocity

[image]Surface is smooth.
Block 2 is at rest initially.
Block 1 is moving with constant velocity 'u'.
block 1 collides with block 2 and block 2 gets some velocity.
Now applying work energy theorem on block 2

potential energy=0

no external energy, hence change in Kinetic energy is zero
which means initial velocity of block 1 is equal to its final velocity but that does not happens
What is wrong in my approach?

Comment: How are you using the Work-KE theorem to solve this?  You haven't shown us what you are using for the $W$ in $W=\Delta KE$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you apply the work - energy theorem on block 2. **But the work energy theorem says that " the total work done by all the forces acting on the body is equal to the change in kinetic energy of the body ."** There is no description of potential energy in it. 
And that's because Potential Energy is the work done in a conservative field. Potential Energy is a mathematical concept which is used in a conservative field to provide an easy analysis of the situation under consideration.
So in conservative field
 **work done=-change in P.E = change in K.E**
Most importantly P.E is of **A System** not if a single body alone.
Therefore P.E of the system =0 before collision and K.E of the system is the K.E of the 1st block.
After the collision the P.E is 0 but the sum of the K.E of two blocks is equal to the K.E of the 1st block before collision (assuming perfectly elastic collision).
And this is energy conservation.
You need a momentum conservation equation to find the final velocities.
I leave that to you